# HTML - iPhone fails to load image

Tags: html, iphone, image, png

The PNG-pictures on my website www.forksandknives.tk load perfectly when you view the page on a computer, but somehow an iPhone fails to load the picture under the "contact" session properly. It is only showing half the picture. Why is this? I have tried reuploading the picture on the server, but still it doesn't help. Any comments are much appreciated.

Comment: Maybe something went wrong at one time and only half the image arrived. So have you cleared the cache?

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that was a possibility! :-)